# Jsonからの独自アダプターによるListの作成の際にimageがたまにしか表示されない

Tags: android, java

サーバー(PC)にある画像を取得して、ListViewのimageに表示させたいのですが、
ほんのたまにしか表示出来ません。
権限は宣言済み
サーバー側では200の成功と出ているので接続が失敗したとも考えられません。
どなたかimageを表示させる方法が
お分かりの方がいらっしゃいましたら
教えていただきたいです。宜しくお願いします

```
case R.id.navigation_notifications:
            String strJson = "[{\"id\": takesi, \"n_id\": \"123\", \"time\": 20},{\"id\": hana, \"n_id\": \"234\", \"time\": 21},{\"id\": risa, \"n_id\": \"345\", \"time\": 22}]";

            Gson gson = new Gson();
            Notification[] notification_array_type = gson.fromJson(strJson,Notification[].class);

            final ArrayList<listitem> notification_array = new ArrayList<>();

            for(Notification user : notification_array_type) {
                listitem noti_item = new listitem("http://192.168.11.11/user_images/" + user.id + ".png",user.id);
                Log.i("test","192.168.11.11/user_images/" + user.id + ".png : " + user.id);
                notification_array.add(noti_item);
            }

            // 出力結果をリストビューに表示
            ListAdapter noti_adapter = new ListAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.main_item, notification_array);
            mListView.setAdapter(noti_adapter);
            noti_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            return true;
```

listitem.java

```
public class listitem {
    private Bitmap mThumbnail = null;
    private String mTitle = null;

    /**
     * 空のコンストラクタ
     */
    public listitem() {};

    /**
     * コンストラクタ
     * @param image_url サムネイル画像
     * @param title タイトル
     */
    public listitem(final String image_url, final String title) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    // URL設定
                    URL url = new URL(image_url);
                    // HTTP接続開始
                    HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    c.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    c.connect();
                    // ダウンロード開始
                    InputStream is = c.getInputStream();
                    mThumbnail = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
                    c.disconnect();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Bitmap bmp = null;
                }
            }
        }).start();

        mTitle = title;
    }

    /**
     * サムネイル画像を設定
     * @param thumbnail サムネイル画像
     */
    public void setThumbnail(Bitmap thumbnail) {
        mThumbnail = thumbnail;
    }

    /**
     * タイトルを設定
     * @param title タイトル
     */
    public void setmTitle(String title) {
        mTitle = title;
    }

    /**
     * サムネイル画像を取得
     * @return サムネイル画像
     */
    public Bitmap getThumbnail() {
        return mThumbnail;
    }

    /**
     * タイトルを取得
     * @return タイトル
     */
    public String getTitle() {
        return mTitle;
    }
}
```

ListAdapter.java

```
public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<listitem> {

    private int mResource;
    private List<listitem> mItems;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    /**
     * コンストラクタ
     * @param context コンテキスト
     * @param resource リソースID
     * @param items リストビューの要素
     */
    public ListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<listitem> items) {
        super(context, resource, items);

        mResource = resource;
        mItems = items;
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view;

        if (convertView != null) {
            view = convertView;
        }
        else {
            view = mInflater.inflate(mResource, null);
        }

        // リストビューに表示する要素を取得
        listitem item = mItems.get(position);

        // サムネイル画像を設定
        ImageView thumbnail = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        thumbnail.setImageBitmap(item.getThumbnail());

        // タイトルを設定
        TextView title = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        title.setText(item.getTitle());

        return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

コンストラクタ内で画像を非同期で読み込んでいるため、リストのアイテム表示時に画像の読み込みが完了していないケースがあるから画像が表示されないのではないでしょうか。
画像の読み込みが完了したタイミングを通知するか、Adapterの中で画像の読み込みを行うかすると良いでしょう。

そもそもHttpURLConnectionを使って画像の読み込みを行うのは今回のケースだとあまり良い方法とは思えないので、PicassoやGlideなど各種画像ライブラリを使うことを検討してみては？

Answer (score 0):

StrictModeを使用すると表示できました
あまりいい方法とは言えないのかもしれませんが...
listitem.java

```
    public listitem(final String image_url, final String title) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
            try {
                // URL設定
                URL url = new URL(image_url);
                // HTTP接続開始
                HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                c.setRequestMethod("GET");
                c.connect();
                // ダウンロード開始
                InputStream is = c.getInputStream();
                mThumbnail = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
                c.disconnect();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Bitmap bmp = null;
            }

    mTitle = title;
        }
```